# How to retrieve array of type array fields with Elasticsearch by array and retrieve if at least one matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I have circumstances, I use bool and filter, search for array with field type array on array, and if I match even one, I want to get it, but it does not work

When searching with `['one', 'two', 'three']`, you want to get something with even one array data as below

```
{
  "created_at": "2018-01-01",
  "tag": ['one']
},
{
  "created_at": "2018-01-01",
  "tag": ['one', 'four', 'ten']
},
{
  "created_at": "2018-01-01",
  "tag": ['two', 'three', 'ten']
},
```

I tried it variously as below, but it does not work

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"terms": {"tag": ['one', 'two', 'three']}}
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {"bool": {"should": {"terms": {"tag": ['one', 'two', 'three']}}}
     }
   }
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": ????
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `terms` should do exactly what you need done. If it doesn't then you might need to run an [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) query on a document you expect to match to see why it's not matched

Answer (score 0):

Terms query filters documents that have fields that match any of the provided terms (not analyzed).

```
GET /_search 

{
    "query": {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                 "bool" : {
                    "should" : { "terms" : { "tag" : ["one","two","three"] } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I am simplifying with the question, I'd like to search in the nest of `bool -> filter`